# Promisify apply() method that uses unknown number of input variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, arguments, prototype, apply

I currently have this piece of code

```
let multiplyTwoNum = (foo, bar, cb) => {
  cb(null, foo * bar)
}

let multiplyThreeNum = (foo, bar, param, cb) => {
  cb(null, foo * bar * param)
}

function multiplyAnyNumbers(f) {
  f.apply(null, Array().slice.call(arguments, 1));
}
```

The above defines two basic functions that multiply the numbers passed on to them and return the value via a callback

Now I can call these two functions as follows. Everything works well till this point. The callback does get much more complicated and I want the multiplyAnyNumber to return a Promise instead.

```
multiplyAnyNumbers(multiplyTwoNum, 1, 2, (err, val) => {
  console.log(err) // Shows undefined
  console.log(val) // Shows 2
});

multiplyAnyNumbers(multiplyThreeNum, 1, 2, 3, (err, val) => {
  console.log(err) // Shows undefined
  console.log(val) // Shows 6
});
```

I want to use it like this instead, which means the callback function wont be passed in the actual function call, and a promise is expected to be returned

```
multiplyAnyNumbers(multiplyThreeNum, 1, 2, 3)
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))

multiplyAnyNumbers(multiplyTwoNum, 1, 2)
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

My attempt causes an error saying "cb is not a function", referring to the 2nd line in the multiply number functions.

```
function multiplyAnyNumbersNew(f) {
  let func = (err, val) => {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(val);
  }
  arguments[(arguments.length).toString()] = (err, val) => {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(val);
  }
  f.apply(null, Array().slice.call(arguments, 1));
}
```

It is important I am able to return a Promise, as if I have to pass the callback then using this doesn't reduce the code I will need to write, since the chunk (~40 lines) of code is in the callback itself. Looking for any advice, in case this question is vague, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Why promisify `multiplyAnyNumbers` instead of promisifying `multiplyTwoNum` and `multiplyThreeNum`?

Comment: I don't get the purpose of `multiplyAnyNumbers`. Where would you use that and pass an `f`, instead of simply calling `f` directly?

Comment: Are you using any particular promise library? Many have the tools that you are looking for on board.

Comment: @Bergi am using Bluebird right now

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use apply. You can do it this way:

```
let multiplyTwoNum = (foo, bar) => Promise.resolve(foo * bar);

let multiplyThreeNum = (foo, bar, param) => Promise.resolve(foo * bar * param);

let multiplyAnyNumbers = (...args) =>
    Promise.resolve(Array().slice.call(args).reduce((a,b)=>a*b));

multiplyTwoNum(2, 5).then((val)=>console.log(val));
multiplyThreeNum(2, 5, 7).then((val)=>console.log(val));
multiplyAnyNumbers(1,3,5,7,9).then((val)=>console.log(val));
multiplyAnyNumbers(3,5).then((val)=>console.log(val));
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0z1atb37/9/

Comment: Just use `Promise.resolve` instead of the promise constructor if you're not doing any actually asynchronous work. Though of course you shouldn't use promises at all in that case.

Comment: @Bergi Improved the answer based on what you commented. Didn't new Promise could be used like that. Thanks.